# When designing a RPC library, how can I allow users change serialization format?

Tags: haskell

I feel that type class instances should be defined only when there is a single valid implementation for them and serialization isn't one of these cases.

Primarily because serialization is a gateway to IO and things happen on the other side.

So, suppose I want to create a convenience library that parses JSON input that comes from some external service provider. How can I allow users to adapt the format if the provider makes an syntactic change out of the blue?

I feel that general answer is to let user "pass record of functions around"...
but derived `FromJSON` instances are so convenient to provide!

Is having `FromJSON` instance a good thing? Should my library use it? I'm worried about instance "leaking" since instances are global. Can I not export it but still offer default serialization for users?

Comment: You might want to read this (not yet complete, just started yesterday) series of blog posts, starting with https://harry.garrood.me/blog/down-with-show-part-1/. It specifically mentions the goal of having one "obvious" instance per type.

Comment: Have you considered using backpack to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How likely is it that the external service provider changes their JSON format without changing the semantics?  If I need to write a new Haskell type because there are more / fewer fields, then I have a new type, and can add new JSON instances.

If such changes are rare, it might still be worth the convenience of instance-directed resolution most of the time.  I can vendor your library or make a newtype during the occasional weeks when I must have a new feature and you haven't yet updated the library.

If you don't want to bless the JSON instances as canonical, but still want the convenient Template Haskell derived functions, I believe [mkJSON](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html#v:mkToJSON) and `mkParseJSON` generate the implementation, which you can export as ordinary functions.

I always appreciate libraries that provide both type-class directed versions of their interface, and versions with explicit function parameters.